# Performance benchmark numbers of grpc using c# compare to java/c++

Tags: c#, grpc

From the benchmark grpc doc https://performance-dot-grpc-testing.appspot.com/explore?dashboard=5636470266134528

it seems GRPC using C# is almost 10 times less efficient than Java/C++ for both streaming and unary rpc calls. Is it an issue with how benchmarking numbers are derived or grpc is generally slow with c#?

[image]

Comment: c# is managed code so there performance against c++ is always slower.  It looks like c# performance is 30% to 40% of c++ which is normal (not 10 times).

Comment: If we look at QPS for Streaming call, C++ QPS is 1.4 Million QPS as of the latest data while C# is around 155K which is almost 9 times less. For unary calls, C# is 59K while C++ is 622K while is more than 10 times.

Comment: ??? (400,000/1,500,000 = 26.6%) and (750,000/2,000,000 = 37.5%).

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting those numbers If you look at the images posted above taken from the dashboard and look at Jul 20 datapoint it clearly reflects the number that I posted before.

Comment: The light blue line from top graph divided by the light blue line in 2nd graph.  The dark blue line from top graph divided by the dark blue line in second graph.

Comment: I don't think that's how the calculation is done. The calculation is within the same graph. In the above graph, black color denotes C++, while violet denotes c sharp.